# unable to populate combo box values from db

Tags: jsf-2

i have two beans DoctorDetailsBean,PatientDetailsBean ,want to populate a combo box with all doctor names in patientRegistration.xhtml

```
     <h:selectOneMenu value="#{patientDetailsBean.refDr}" style="font-size: medium" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{patientDetailsBean.drDetailsbeanList}" var="dr"       itemLabel="#{dr.doctorName}" itemValue="#{dr.doctorId}" />
     </h:selectOneMenu>
```

DoctorDetailsBean:

```
       @ManagedBean(name="doctorBean")
       @SessionScoped
       public class DoctorDetailsBean {
       private Long doctorId;
       private String doctorName;
       private String place;
       private Long phoneNumber;
       //setters&getters
        }
```

PatientdetailsBean:

```
       @ ManagedBean(name= "patientDetailsBean")
       @SessionScoped
       public class PatientDetailsBean implements Serializable {
       private Long patientId;
       private String patientName;
       private long refDr;

@ManagedProperty (value ="#{doctorBean}")
private DoctorDetailsBean doctorDetailsBean;
private List<Doctor> drList;
private List<DoctorDetailsBean> drDetailsbeanList;
private PatientDAO patientDAO;
private DoctorDAO doctorDAO;
   //setters&getters
  public PatientDetailsBean() {
   }
     @PostConstruct  
 public void init() throws AppException,AppSysException{
     drList = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
     drList = doctorDAO.getAllDoctors();
     drDetailsbeanList = new ArrayList<DoctorDetailsBean>();
           for (Doctor doctor : drList) {
            DoctorDetailsBean  doctorDetailsBean  = new DoctorDetailsBean();
            doctorDetailsBean.setDoctorId(doctor.getDoctorId());
            doctorDetailsBean.setDoctorName(doctor.getDoctorName());
            doctorDetailsBean.setPlace(doctor.getPlace());
            doctorDetailsBean.setPhoneNumber(doctor.getPhoneNumber());
            drDetailsbeanList.add(doctorDetailsBean);
                      }            }
```

How to solve my problem

Comment: What's the issue? You can't figure out how to display your drDetailsbeanList as a selectOneMenu ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with type of `drDetailsbeanList`. `List<DoctorDetailsBean>` is not correct. Create method which returns `List<SelectItem>` and use it in xhtml.